# Combining Two 2TB disks and One RAID-10 Array into A Single Logical Volume?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, postgresql, database, lvm

Is it possible to combine 2 disk and 1 RAID array into 1 single logical volume in Ubuntu 18.04?

I am planning to set up a PostgreSQL database on this machine and think it is better to let it store data in 1 single volume than to span across multiple volumes (which I believe require manual config like creating multiple tablespaces).

My system is currently configured to have

1. `/dev/sda5`: 2 TB Drive (containing Ubuntu 18.04)
2. `/dev/sdb`: 2 TB Drive (Empty)
3. `/dev/md0`: RAID-10 Array (2 TB Usable, Software RAID using mdadm, empty)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:** yes, you can do that via LVM, but **don't do that**. Simply install PostgreSQL on the current RAID1 array.

**Long answer:** LVM has the concept of *linear concatenation* of multiple physical volume to create a single logical volume. However, in this case a single failed physical disks will destroy your volume, leading to **unrecoverable and complete data loss.** Moreover, in you case `sda5` is not empty, and this poses additional complexity.

You *could* work around that, and create a second RAID1 array between `sda` and `sdb`, then concatenate the two RAID arrays in a single logical volume. Alternatively, you could rely on [LVM own RAID management](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/lvmraid.7.html) (`--type raid1`) but, again, this is a quite complex setup starting from your current configuration.

I suggest to skip this complexity and to simply use `/dev/md0` to store your PostgreSQL database: 2 TB is quite a lot of space for many databases and, if they really are not enough, you probably need to start from scratch with a more sensible setup.

Answer (score 1):

As it is usually the case with any striping RAID's levels *the more disks RAID contains the better it handles workload*. I'd suggest hence expanding RAID10 over all of the disks — and then you can combine remainder of 2 bigger disks into another RAID (RAID1 specifically) which can be used for system partition and other stuff that doesn't have high performance requirements.

Comment: My current RAID-10 array `/dev/md0` consists of four 1TB disks. Is it possible to expand this RAID-10 array over the 2TB disk `/dev/sdb`, since there will be an odd number of drives and the drive sizes are no longer all the same.

Comment: Linux Software RAID supports odd number of disks for RAID10, and you’d of course better use only a fraction of bigger disk (IOW “partition”), using the rest for RAID1. Also I’d recommend rebuilding RAID10 with use of all disks, totalling to 6 instead of 5, in similar manner.

Comment: Thanks. If my OS is on one of the drives `/dev/sda`, can it be used in the new RAID10 array?

Comment: Or are you suggesting that the drive `/dev/sda` containing the OS be partitioned, for example, into two 1TB partitions. Then create the new RAID10 to include 1TB partition from `/dev/sda`, 2 TB from `/dev/sdb`, and 4x1TB from the initial RAID10 `/dev/md0`? Giving about 3.75 TB of usable space? The OS will remain on the 1TB partition which does not belong to any RAID array.

Comment: I explained it in the answer. Partition bigger disks so that you can use part of them both in R10 on 6 disks and R1 on 2. GRUB supports booting from R1 as well. Of course it’s better to use LVM-2 on top of those RAIDs for flexibility but it’s up to you.